# Simple ajax in laravel 4

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

i have following code

**ajax**

```
 //ajax edit button
 $('.edit_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_produk = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "editproduk",
        data : id_produk,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success : function(data) {
           alert('Success');
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: alert('Errors')
    });
});
```

i always get messagebox **error**
and don't know where i'm missing,
because in chrome - inspect element - console not give any clue

**my route**

```
Route::post('/account/editproduk', array(
    'as' => 'edit-produk-post',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@postEditProduk'
));
```

**my controller**

```
public function postEditProduk() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        return "test test";
    }
}
```

---

**extended question**
i running my script well after using `return Response::json()` like this

```
$id_produk = Input::get('id_produk');
$produk = Produk::findOrFail($id_produk);
return Response::json($produk);
```

and access it in view by this script

```
success : function(data) {
    alert('Success');
    console.log(data["name-produk"]);
}
```

but if i want to return array json like

```
$id_produk = Input::get('id_produk');
$produk = Produk::findOrFail($id_produk);
$spesifikasi = SpesifikasiProduk::where('id_produk', '=', $id_produk);
return Response::json(array($produk, $spesifikasi));
```

i can't access it in view like this...

```
success : function(data1, data2) {
    alert('Success');
    console.log(data1["name-produk"] - data2["title-spek"]);
}
```

how to access json array

---

**extended question update**

if i'm wrong please correct my script
because i get a litle confused with explenation

is this correct way to return it?

```
Response::json(array('myproduk' => 'Sproduk', 'data2' => 'testData2'));
```

result

```
console.log(produk["myproduk"]);
--------------------------------
Object {id_produk: 1, nama_produk: "produk1", deskripsi: "desc_produk" 


console.log(produk["data2"]);
--------------------------------
testData2
```

and i still don't have idea how to print `nama_produk` in `my_produk`array

Comment: I am in laravel 5, so maybe this won't work for you, but I send the JSON response back using `return Response::json(array('successMessage' => 'Success', 'payload' => $response));`. Also can you put logs inside your controller so that we can be sure its a problem in client side, not the server side. Also if your button `.edit_button` is submitting some form, you might want to do `e.preventDefault()` function before you send the ajax request. Do the above steps and let me know what the results were

Comment: @Rash when i return JSON using your script..it's give error "500 internal Server Error" and i already try add prefentDefault function before i define var id_produk and nothing change....can u give me link how to see log inside my controller? because i don't have idea how to do it

Comment: laravel comes with a log facade. Look into your app.php inside config folder. There must be a facade named Log. In your controller at the top write `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log` and wherever you want to log just write `Log::error("some log");` This is in laravel 5. Dont know about 4 but will check if you can't find it.

Comment: Also you mentioned earlier that you get 500 Error when you executed my code. Can you specify the reason why? Maybe you forgot to define `$response` and hence the error.

Comment: @Rash yeah i forgot define $response..that why i get 500 error

Comment: @rash please see my extended question

Comment: Hi. Check my answer. Hope you like it. If there is anything else, let me know. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81924/discussion-between-rash-and-neversaysblack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Why is this code not sending JSON data back.

```
public function postEditProduk() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        return "test test";
    }
}
```

**Answer:** Because this is not the right way to send the JSON data back.
From the Laravel 4 docs, [the right way](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses) to send JSON data back is linked. Hence the correct code becomes:

```
public function postEditProduk() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        return Response::json("test test");
    }
}
```

**Question 2:**
Why am I not able to access the data in `data1` and `data2`

```
success : function(data1, data2) {
    alert('Success');
    console.log(data1["name-produk"] - data2["title-spek"]);
}
```

**Answer:** Because this is not the right way to catch the JSON data. The right way to send is given in the [Laravel 4 API reference docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.html#method_json).

```
static JsonResponse json(string|array $data = array(), int $status = 200, array $headers = array(), int $options)
```

As you can see the method `json` takes `string` or `array` as the first parameter. So you need to send all your data in the first parameter itself (which you are doing). Since you passed only `one` parameter, you have to catch only 1 parameter in your javascript. You are catching 2 parameters.

Depending on what `$produk` and `$spesifikasi` is, your data will be present in one single array. Lets say that `$produk` is a string and `$spesifikasi` is an array. Then your data on the javascript side will be this:

```
[
    [0] => 'value of $produk',
    [1] => array [
        [0] => 'value1',
        [1] => 'value2'
    ]
]
```

It would be best if you print the log your entire data and know the structure. Change your code to this:

```
success : function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
}
```

This will print your entire data and then you can see the structure of your data and access it accordingly. If you need help with printing the data on your console, google it, or just let me know.

I sincerely hope that I have explained your doubts clearly. Have a nice day.

## Edit

**extended question answer:**
Replace this line:

```
$spesifikasi = SpesifikasiProduk::where('id_produk', '=', $id_produk);
```

With this:

```
$spesifikasi = SpesifikasiProduk::where('id_produk', '=', $id_produk)->get();
```

Without calling the `get()` method, laravel will not return any value.

Then access your data in javascript like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This way you will get to know the structure of your data and you can access it like:

```
data[0]["some_key"]["some_other_key"];
```

Comment: hm wait a minute...get a little confused
i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you're returning text while your ajax request awaits json data, look at these lines of codes, I think you should get your answer:

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
        $province = Input::get('selectedProvince');
        //Get all cites for a province
        if ($cityList = City::where('province_id','=', $province)) {
            return Response::make($cityList->get(['id', 'name']));
        }
        return Response::json(array('success' => false), 400);
    }
```

Comment: please see my extended question